# How to retrieve data from parse to android?

Tags: android

Please help me!How can I retrieve data from parse after the user login and take it to another activity and put it in a TextView ? here is my first activity where the user will login.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Parse.initialize(this, "SMXvtOppMAR1x2NsGb0eJ4vr8qKCOLKKDilnv4",
            "Ro7d1xT87p7GvnAIguHEhu7V7CuVPCEqbqY7qs");

    userID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserId);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    txtuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserID);
    txtpassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butLogin);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            ID1 = userID.getText().toString();
            ID =Integer.parseInt(ID1);

            query  = ParseQuery.getQuery("SUPERVISOR");
            query.whereEqualTo("Supervisor_ID",ID);
            query.whereEqualTo("Supervisor_Password", password.getText().toString());
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject result, ParseException e) 
                {
                    if (result != null) {
                        // Go to the supervisor screen
                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,
                                SupervisorScreen.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        // invalid user name
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Invalid user name and password",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the other activity where it should display his name and the lab number and department.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.supervisor_screen);
    Parse.initialize(this, "SMXvtOppMAR1x2NsG1zb0eJ4vqKCOLKKDilnv4",
            "Ro7d1xT87p7GvnAIguHEhu7V7CuVPCEqbqY7qs");

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtnamesuper);
    lab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtlabnumsup);
    department = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdepartmentsup);
    addinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butAddInfo);
    maintinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butMaintenInfo);
}
}
```

Comment: Pass the respective values through intent

Comment: Read https://parse.com/docs/android_guide and https://parse.com/tutorials#android, then get back if you still have problems.

Comment: Why when I write like this 
int num=query.getInt("Lab_Relation");
it gives me error in getInt like it doesn't accept it?